# How to specify a line segment in space(3D)?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let us take two points (x,y,z) and (a,b,c) in space.

The line passing through it has direction ratio (x-a);(y-b);(z-c) and using any of the passing point we can specify this line (in vector form A+α(B) ) .

What I want to know is there a way of specifying line segment passing with end points as (x,y,z) and (a,b,c) in space? I mean we can find a unique line but can we define a line segment in space?

( I only happen to have elementry knowledge of 3D -geometry standard form of equation of plane and line, direction cosine , etc so if you can keep the answer simple it would help, if one should exist)

Comment: If you’re wondering how to refer to such an object, I recommend saying, “the line segment from $P$ to $Q$”, if those are the endpoints. Chances are that most people would interpret “$\overline{PQ}$” correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=(a,b,c)$ and let $Q=(x,y,z)$. Then the line segment $PQ$ is the following set of points:

$$PQ=\{t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)\,\vert\,t\in[0,1]\}.$$

In other words, the points on the line segment $PQ$ are the points that can be expressed as

$$t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)$$

for some $t$ with $0\le t\le1$.

**Edit:** I was asked to give some justification of the above claim.

We have that $P=(a,b,c)$ and $Q=(x,y,z)$.

One way to parametrize the line $PQ$, is to note that points on the line are points of the form

$$P+t\cdot\vec{PQ}$$

where $t$ is a scalar. $\vec{PQ}$ is the vector going from $P$ to $Q$. Hence $\vec{PQ}$ can be represented as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\vec{PQ} &= Q-P \\
&= (x,y,z)-(a,b,c) \\
&= (x-a,y-b,z-c)
\end{align*}$$

Hence points on the line $PQ$ can be represented as

$$\begin{align*}
P+t\cdot\vec{PQ} &= (a,b,c)+t\cdot(x-a,y-b,z-c) \\
&= (a,b,c)+t\cdot\left[((x,y,z)-(a,b,c)\right] \\
&= t\cdot(x,y,z)+(a,b,c)-t\cdot(a,b,c) \\
&= t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)
\end{align*}$$

for some scalar $t$. So we've established that every point on line $PQ$ can be written as

$$t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)$$

for some scalar $t$.

Now note the following: if $t=0$, then

$$t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)=(a,b,c)=P.$$

And if $t=1$, then

$$t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)=(x,y,z)=Q.$$

And if we let $0<t<1$, then $t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)$ will be a point between $P$ and $Q$.

It follows that the line segment $PQ$ consists of all points of the form

$$t\cdot(x,y,z)+(1-t)\cdot(a,b,c)$$

where $t$ is a scalar with $0\le t\le1$.

Comment: It might be worth point out that this parameterization applies in any number of dimensions.

Comment: @amd You're absolutely right, and that is a good thing to point out. When I posted my answer, the main audience that I had in mind was the person who posted the original question. Since the person who posted the original question indicated that he only had elementary knowledge of 3D-geometry, I thought I should avoid making my answer too general.

Comment: Can you outline the proof if it is not too advanved ? Just a weblink to proof will help. Also, Thanks for the answer

Comment: @HrishabhNayal No, the dot just means multiplication. Note that $t$ is a scalar. So $1-t$ is also a scalar. $t\cdot(x,y,z)=(tx,ty,tz)$. Etc.

Comment: @HrishabhNayal I added to the end of my post, so that the post now includes some justification of the claims I made. If you have additional questions, let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for the proof I totally understand it now. Also no doubts very well explained:-)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for posting the problem!